# Azure Service Bus Topic missing data across subcriptions

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-topics, azure-servicebus-subscriptions

I am facing a weird scenario where I have an SB topic and it has two subscriptions Sub1 and Sub1.
I have two listeners for each of the Subscriptions (no other listeners apart from mine)
`Sub1 => Listener1`
`Sub2 => Listener2`

Have been seeing issues where a msg is seen by Listener2/1 and completely missed by the other. No exceptions, no dead letters etc. Is there even a slightest possibility that it might happen at the SB level? What all can I check here for troubleshooting?

Comment: What's the subscription rules/filter on those two ASB subscriptions? There's a chance that those are not set up correctly and messages are discarded.

Comment: No, we do not have any filters and it happens occasionally like an average of 200-300 missing messages per month. We also have successful ones that are being processed by both in huge numbers ~1.5 million a month. So unsure what might be wrong here.

Comment: There's always a filter. A default filter (catch-all) is a filter. I can more than guarantee the broker doesn't lose the messages. It's either the topology setup or the app. Unfortunately, I have nothing but your description to base my troubleshooting on, and that's not a very effective strategy  What would help is the details about your ASB topology, sender code, receiver code. In my entire experience with ASB, I have not seen messages lost if they were successfully dispatched and received by the broker.

Comment: Are you using ReceiveAndDelete or PeekLock? If you're using ReceiveAndDelete, once the broker successfully delivers a message, it is gone, regardless of if the receiver was able to handle the message appropriately (including networking blips, etc).

Comment: It is peekLock David. I have added more telemetry at client side to see what might be happening.